# Scrolling on touch screen dramatically slows down AJAX download time on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm seeing some strange behavior where an AJAX request just hangs occationally when scrolling with the finger, as long as your finger is held down. It's hard to describe the issue in words, so take a look at this fiddle:

```
$("div").on('scroll', infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax);

function infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax(){
$("div").off("scroll");
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : "/someURL",
       data: {data: "data"}

     })
     .done(function(response) {
       $("div").append("<br>appendedData");
       $("div").on('scroll', infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax);
     })
     .fail(function() {
       $("div").append("<br>appendedError");
       $("div").on('scroll', infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax);
     });
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rx1qj9L5/5/

It fires an AJAX request (to a non-existant URL) and gets an error back. The AJAX request is fired on the `scroll` event. When you use the mouse scroll, the average time is between 80-200 ms. This seems to be very consistant.

Here's where the trouble comes in. When scrolling with the finger, the ajax request can get stuck in "downloading content" **INDEFINATELY** until the finger is released from scrolling!

using the following steps, I'm able to reproduce consistantly:

1. Get a fresh reload of the page above on a touch-enabled device (in Google Chrome)
2. Open chrome dev tools, go to the network tab
3. touch down on the scrollable div (don't let go!) scroll up and down while holding your finger down.
4. This will fire 3 ajax calls, the third of which WILL HANG INDEFINATELY UNTIL YOU RELEASE YOUR FINGER. This only happens when scrolling with the finger inside google chrome.
5. The instant you release your finger, you'll see the Ajax goes through.

I can't think of any reason for this behavior. Has anyone encountered this? Would there be any workaround to this issue?

p.s. - I've tried doing the same bindings in vanilla Javascript. No differences. :/

Comment: ajaxing on scroll events is a bad idea

Comment: @madalinivascu ok, than how does facebook do it? or google plus? or any other page with infinite scrolling?

Comment: it checks if the user has reach the bottom of the page

Comment: then triggers the ajax

Comment: @madalinivascu does it just check every 1 second or something then? what's the trigger?

Comment: it uses a thing called math to calculate on scroll if the user is a the bottom of the page

Comment: @madalinivascu yes. I think I've heard of math. I'm asking what EVENT you are saying to do the said math on. No triggering event = no math. Are you saying to do the math on the `scroll` event? because I've tried that, and unfortunately it does the same thing :/

Comment: you do the math in the scroll event, if the scroll is at the bottom you trigger only **one** ajax call

Comment: @madalinivascu yes, that was the idea. The code here is cut down to the bare minimum to express the nature of the issue. Adding that "if" statement doesn't solve the problem (I wish it did) It just makes the error harder to reproduce (one in five instead of every time)

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason for this behavior. Since JavaScript by default is single-threaded, while scrolling on touch-enabled devices, the thread is paused. (I feel like disabling the "passive" nature of the event should have solved the issue, but the thread is *still* paused)

However, there is a solution. If you spawn a html5 WebWorker, *JavaScript is no longer single threaded*. The WebWorker gets it's own thread, and scrolling no longer causes any issues.

Doing some of my own tests with ajax in a webworker, the ajax is consistently faster, and it works flawlessly with scrolling. It's the smoothest infinite scroll I've ever seen!

The ajax through the webworker seems to work better all around (probably because it gets it's own dedicated thread?) but *especially* for mobile chrome, where ajax is *paused* during scrolling, and continues to be held for a 1-2 second pause *after* the scrolling. Using the web worker allows the ajax to complete before the scrolling even stops, and so it gives the illusion of seamless scrolling indefinitely.

Here's my (dependant free) solution for calling an ajax function with a web worker:

### function in main page's js:

```
// wajax (webworker ajax)
function wajax(obj)
{

  var sendObj = {};

  sendObj.url  = obj.url;
  sendObj.data = obj.data;
  sendObj.csrf = {{csrfToken here}}; //make sure to fill this out if you're using csrf tokens


  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof(ajaxWorker) === "undefined") {
      ajaxWorker = new Worker("path/to/webworker.js");
    }


    ajaxWorker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(sendObj));

    ajaxWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
      obj.success(event.data);
    };
  }
  else {
    // This means webworkers aren't available. Here, just do a regular ajax call....
  }
}
```

### Webworker (separate script / thread from the page's javascript):

The webworker has code I derived from the jQuery source code to allow JSON objects to be used in AJAX calls. I stripped down the source code to the bare minimum. Full size of webworker is only around 80 lines before minifying.

```
/* ADAPTED FROM JQUERY SOURCE */
function param(a)
{
  var prefix,
      params = [],
      add    = function(key, value) {
        params[params.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value == null ? "" : value);
      };

  for (prefix in a) {
    buildParams(prefix, a[prefix], add);
  }

  // Return the resulting serialization
  return params.join("&");
}

function buildParams(mainKey, mainValue, add)
{
  var name;
  var length = mainValue.length;
  if (Array.isArray(mainValue)) {
    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      var value = mainKey[index];
      if (/\[]$/.test(mainKey)) {
        add(mainKey, value);
      }
      else {
        buildParams(mainKey + "[" + (typeof value === "object" && value != null ? index : "") + "]", value, add);
      }
    }
  }
  else if (typeof mainValue === "object") {
    for (name in mainValue) {
      buildParams(mainKey + "[" + name + "]", mainValue[name], add);
    }
  }
  else {
    add(mainKey, mainValue);
  }
}

/* END CODE ADAPTED FROM JQUERY SOURCE */

/*
* Created by Skeets 2017-12-13
* */

onmessage = function(e) {

  var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);

  obj.data._token = obj.csrf;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', obj.url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success
      var output;
      try {
        output = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      }
      catch (e) {
        output = request.responseText;
      }
      postMessage(output);
    }
    else {
      // error
      console.log(request.responseText);
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // connection error
  };

  request.send(param(obj.data));

};
```

Once this is in place, you can just make an ajax request like so:

```
wajax({
  url    : "/some/url",
  data   : {value_a:"somestuff",value_b:2},
  success: function(response) {
    // do something with the response
  }
});
```

Feel free to use and adapt this code.

Comment: this issue you reported is present on desktop as well, If you scroll down and keep the mouse scroll button going up and down the ajax get stuck for as long as you keep doing this, also if you are just scrolling down very fast every 3-4:th ajax call gets stuck for 2-5 seconds and interupts smooth scrolling. Have you noticed this on desktop with your first implementation?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it on my system, but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a similar issue on Mac desktops, if there's "smooth scrolling" in the browser (I'm not super familiar with Mac desktops). However, using a webworker is definately the correct answer here. It will run smoother for desktop, mobile, everything. Your infinite scrolling gets it's own uninterrupted thread. I've tested apple, android, windows, low-end devices, all major browsers. Runs smoother EVERY time. (P.S., the only reason the other answers are upvoted is because I upvoted them. :P)

Comment: we are using vuejs and it seems we cant use web-worker together with ajax call, did you use pure javascript? I'm on win10 and my developing partner on mac and we both have problems with delays in ajax calls due to fast scrolling down, just like you described, every once in a while we get a ajax call that takes up to 5 seconds to respond. Its driving us nuts for days now not being able to solve it.

Comment: @nikocraft Ok, I've edited my answer to include full code examples. There's no library dependancies, so it should work for you.

Comment: hi @skeets I just found something that seems solution to all our problems, no web-workers are needed, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API it has good browser support and for IE you can use polyfill.

Comment: If Oberver API does not work, I'll test your solution, many thanks! :)

Comment: well it seems like Observer API is not perfect solution either, gonna try your solution above, holding fingers it works :)

Comment: just to confirm I got web-worker to work with vuejs and now I got smooth almost instant infinite scrolling, amazing! thanks to the Skeets for making this post, I was not even aware this thing would be an issue and was scratching my head for days with this.

Comment: Sure thing! I'm glad finally someone sees that I'm not crazy, and that this is definately an issue worth spending the time to solve :D

Comment: no you are not crazy, I thought me and my coding partner where the crazy ones and wondered how no-one in the world has run into this issue, well I am glad you did 7 months ago and posted about it! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't think of any reason for this behavior.

Most-likely this is to reduce the amount of JavaScript that runs while the user is scrolling, to make scrolling smoother. While JavaScript runs, it blocks UI updates, which could lead to some janky scrolling (especially if there is some heavy DOM manipulation).

> Has anyone encountered this?

I found a Chromium issue someone filed that sounds like the same issue: [setTimeout and XHR requests are ignored while user is scrolling](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=661155). Looks like it was closed due to uncertainty that the exists though.

> Would there be any workaround to this issue?

Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the ajax when the user is at the bottom of the page

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : "/someURL",
       data: {data: "data"}

     })
     .done(function(response) {
       $("div").append("<br>appendedData");
     })
     .fail(function() {
       $("div").append("<br>appendedError");
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: I can reproduce the error using this exact code: https://jsfiddle.net/rx1qj9L5/7/

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the xhr request when the ajax request can gets stuck in "downloading content" INDEFINITELY?

Comment: the touch event shouldn't intere with the ajax request,from the screenshot i can see your request go to a 404, can you post the timing for your request? https://i.stack.imgur.com/sleu5.png

Comment: usually you remove your finger after you trigger the ajax

Comment: if my logic is correct javascript is single-threaded so the thread is busy with the tap event so the asynchronous xhr will wait for thread availability ,you can execute 2 function at the same time

Comment: yeah I'm starting to lose hope that this will work the way I wanted it to. Thanks for your efforts anyway :)

Comment: your implementation should do something similar to how you refresh a page in the mobile you slide down and then release for your page to refresh(in your case append the html from the ajax), if you don't release the tap the page isn't refreshed

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking into:

Improving Scroll Performance with Passive Event Listeners

> When you scroll a page and there's such a delay that the page doesn't feel anchored to your finger, that's called scroll jank. Many times when you encounter scroll jank, the culprit is a touch event listener. New to Chrome 51, passive event listeners are an emerging web standard that provide a major potential boost to scroll performance, especially on mobile.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners

Comment: This sounded promising, but unfortunately making the event not passive (it defaults to passive) didn't fix the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is dependent on your machine. Seeing as you're making very frequent AJAX calls, you are depleting your system's resources. This will be especially annoying for your mobile users with low-end devices.

On my laptop, the AJAX requests fired every time I scrolled. However I did get the following violation rather quickly:

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript

This is due to the fact you're modifying the DOM so frequently. See [this post](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) on forced layout/reflow and **layout thrashing**.

What you want to do instead is limit the code that you're processing for every scroll. You can do this by **debouncing** your function (aka limiting the rate at which your function executes).

You can import a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4), which has this [built-in](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce), but that might be overkill if this is the only place you need it. Luckily, it's relatively painless to write our own (basic) `debounce` function:

```
function debounce(func, timeToWait) {

    var timeout;

    return function() {

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(func, timeToWait);
    };
}
```

In the context of your problem, you can use `debounce` to limit the execution rate of `infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax`:

```
var debouncedAjax = debounce(infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax, 500); // debounce here
$("div").on('scroll', debouncedAjax); // use debounced

function infiniteDictionaryScrollAjax() {
    $("div").off("scroll");
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/someURL",
            data: {
                data: "data"
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {

            $("div").append("<br>appendedData");
            $("div").on('scroll', debouncedAjax); // use debounced

        })
        .fail(function() {
            $("div").append("<br>appendedError");
            $("div").on('scroll', debouncedAjax); // use debounced
        });
}

function debounce(func, timeToWait) {

    var timeout;

    return function() {

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(func, timeToWait);
    };
}
```

See a working [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/f1x28975/). Notice the AJAX call runs only 500 milliseconds *after* the user has paused scrolling (which is completely reasonable for mobile devices, as users will pause briefly to look at content as they scroll).

Comment: I'm voting up because reading through this, it could be the answer. Unfortunately, the problem seems to lie somewhere else. The request (a single ajax request, that in no way would overwhelm the system) hangs indefinately in the "download content" phase (content to download is only about 10KB) and as soon as I lift my finger from the screen, it goes through. (the code above was the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem on my machine)