# is it possible to make ajax call inside web-worker with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We are having a problem with infinite scrolling as another developer described here:

[Scrolling on touch screen dramatically slows down AJAX download time on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788146/scrolling-on-touch-screen-dramatically-slows-down-ajax-download-time-on-chrome/)

his solution was to use web workers and make ajax call from web-worker.

We are using vuejs and it seems we cant make ajax calls using web-workers.

We are using vue-worker https://github.com/israelss/vue-worker library that makes it simple to implement web-workers.

Has anyone else made ajax calls from their own thread using web-worker?